# Switch between using test/production IP using Angular 2

Tags: angular, serve

I was thinking I'd like `npm run develop` or `npm run production` to be able to switch IP/domain names easily (and perhaps some other variables).

Currently when serving the app I constantly have to do a replace on "localhost" before serving.

Should this be done in SystemJS somehow?

As for `package.json`:

```
"start": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" "
```

How could this be implemented for an Angular 2 app?

Comment: do that replacement scriptable for npm run script?

Comment: If you are using task runners like gulp or grunt l, you can set the variables in there.

Comment: @Som is there also an npm way to do that?